# Trouble with rpi-source with kernel 4.0.x

Tags: kernel, rpi-source

Since a while I was using [rpi-source](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/) to download kernel source corresponding to the kernel update using `rpi-update`.

As it works great on kernel

```
Linux pib 3.18.14+ #793 PREEMPT Sat May 30 13:15:19 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

It doesnot work with kernel

```
Linux pi2 4.0.7-v7+ #801 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 30 18:38:23 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

On such a kernel it reports :

> ```
> ERROR:
> gcc version check: mismatch between gcc (4.8.4) and /proc/version (4.0.7)
> Skip this check with --skip-gcc
>
> Help: https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki
> ```

A workaround is to add the `--skip-gcc` as the script suggests it.
How to run it without skipping this check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script [rpi-source](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/blob/e947d95aeed19990515a8b558096a0867182d346/rpi-source) extract the gcc version parsing /proc/version with :

```
gcc_ver_kernel = re.findall(r'\d\.\d\.\d', proc_version)
```

And use the first matching occurrence as the gcc release of the current kernel.

This works only if the kernel version doesn't match '\d.\d.\d' and gcc release does. It is correct till the kernel identification have almost one release number with 2 digits.

**Update** :
The problem was fixed this since this [commit](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/commit/b025ca57b715b8d4aeb47998afdda7218aa0e80a)